# Embedding webpage in Flash

Tags: flash

I know very little about Flash, and so is not programming in it. I have a website in PHP, and obviously, HTML, CSS, JS, etc.

What I want to do is to allow users to full-screen certain pieces of the DOM. So my question is, is there any way to wrap flash around certain portions of the DOM dynamically in order to allow full screening of that portion.

Edit:

The current responses are very interesting and could be the only options.

But in my ideal world there would be an embedded flash object, and inside that would be some sort of iframe or the flash equivalent so that the rendering is still handled by the browser and not flash itself.

Comment: Flash is it's own technology by Adobe. A browser itself does not know how to process flash, and because of this things hidden inside it **cannot** be rendered by the browser. This is not possible in any world.

Comment: Is it necessary to use flash?  If not, you could just instruct them to use F11 on windows, or the lifehacker javascript to maximize firefox on OSX.

Comment: It's not necessary to use flash, but it's the only way I know to achieve real 1 click fullscreen.

Instructing them to F11 is not really feasible from a usability standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is very limited to what HTML it can render by itself ( bold,italic,underline, a, ul, li and img I think are the only tags supported ) in the Flash Player. AIR renders full HTML, but that won't help you at all.

You could try and use an html parser. I didn't spent to much time with html in flash, so I don't know which parser does the best job. Here's one that looks ok-ish:

http://code.google.com/p/htmlsprite/

Once you have your html rendered in flash properly, the rest is easy peasy. 
Assuming fullscreen would be your fullscreen button.

```
fullscreen.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullscreenClicked);

function fullscreenClicked(event:MouseEvent):void{

switch(stage.displayState) {
                case StageDisplayState.NORMAL:
                    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;
                    break;
                case StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN:
                default:
                    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
                    break;
            }
            trace('stage.displayState: ' + (stage.displayState));

}
```

As Krish stated, don't forget to set allowFullScreen to true in both *embed* and *object* tags. Also, you can only test in the browser, not in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The standard Flash player does not have the concept of iFrame. With AIR you can embed a browser (WebKit based) within a Flash application, but this is only for desktop applications.

The only real way to do exactly what you want would be to have Flash read out to the DOM via ExternalInterface, pull in the structure of the page, and recreate it in Flash. The complexity of this depends on the complexity of your page and how you choose to render the content you get from the DOM.

Comment: Would javascript work inside flash? Or would I have to make it into flash script or whatever it is.

Answer (score 0):

use allowFullScreen="true"  ine embed tag

```
<embed src="kitchen.swf" allowFullScreen="true" bgcolor="#333333" width="1024" height="576"
 name="fullscreen" align="middle" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if it will fullscreen the *HTML* of the page, then no - I've never heard of anything like that before (not with Flash at least).

You could use some jQuery to accomplish something like this by increasing the scale of the content and the elements inside of a parent element, but it sounds like it would be difficult to say the least.

Comment: Actually I'm doing that, but it's not true full screen. :)