# Is it possible to embed a HTML into a PDF?

Tags: html, pdf

I like to embed a HTML site into a PDF document. Are there any libraries or PDF creator that make that possible?

Update:
I am not looking for ways to convert a HTML to PDF. I actually want to use the HMTL as it is inside the PDF. So I am looking for something like iframe for PDF.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571381/can-you-embed-an-html-webpage-in-a-pdf-file/10772270

Answer (score 0):

There are a few out there, depends if you need to build using PHP or another language. I have used MPDF before: http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its possible using xmlworker5.4.1.jar. The XML worker object allows you to embed html in your document. xmlString object below is your HTML content as HTMLWorker is deprecated so use XMLWorker only.

```
 XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
  String currentLine = "";
                  StringBuffer xmlString = new StringBuffer();
                  xmlString.append("<html><body>");
                  String str = htmlPages[i];
                  xmlString.append(htmlPages[i]);
                  xmlString.append("</body></html>");
                  worker.parseXHtml(pdfWriter, pdfDocument, new StringReader(xmlString.toString()));
```

Inorder to incorporate fonts mentioned in font face tag u need to register fonts using

```
FontFanctory.redisterDirectory("path of font files");
```

because itext doesnt scan system for fonts. u need to register it yourself this way

Comment: Will the HTML still be usable as an HTML or will it be converted to a static document?