# Adding React Component to PDF without having it in the dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

I've for the past many weeks trying to add a react component to a PDF without showing it in the DOM. I've tried to convert it to canvas, but that doesn't work since it is not shown in the Dom and therefor cant be found. So I'm searching for a way to add it to the PDF without rendering it. Would be appreciated if someone could help me with a way to do that.

Comment: Sorry what? You cannot embed html in a pdf: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10571381/can-you-embed-an-html-webpage-in-a-pdf-file

Comment: That is not really what I want. I could transport it to an image, if someone had a suggestion of how that could be done without rendering it on the screen.

Comment: if you are using the PDF option such as print to PDF file, then you can use css media query to display only for the printing purpose 
@media print { 
 /* All your print styles go here */
 #canvasId { display: block !important; } 
}

Comment: Not sure that works neither since display: none kind of removes it from the dom so I can't get it neither. Have you tried it out with display:block/display?

Comment: You just said you don't want to have the component in the DOM...