# How to export a react component as pdf without rendering it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, html2canvas, export-to-pdf

I am trying to export a couple of react components to pdf. I am following [this](https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/how-to-create-pdfs-from-react-components-client-side-solution-7f506d9dfa6d) article for it.

The problem is that my components are not rendered in the DOM and therefore, I cannot use `document.getElementById()`. I looked at a [similar question asked here previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55791690/9184849) but it did not have any answers.

I do have one of the components that I need to export in the DOM but it is small in size and cut in half. When I export that, the pdf also has a small, cut-in-half page.

Help would be appreciated.

Edit: I have a button `export to pdf` that calls a function `exportAsPdf()`. I tried to write the function like this

```js
const comp1 = <Comp1 />
const comp2 = <Comp2 />
```

But it didn't work as these did not have a parent. I also tried `new Comp1().render()` but that also doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to use **pdf** in React, you might check out this package: `https://react-pdf.org/`

Comment: What would you export if the component isn't rendered anywhere? Would https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-to-pdf help?

Comment: @DrewReese I added some details in the question. `react-to-pdf` seems like it is only for a single page? I would prefer 3 pages in my final pdf

Comment: @Prottay the components are already complete. Adding `react-pdf` in now seems like it would be a lot of work. And it doesn't seem like it solves my problem anyways

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? we are running into the same issue?

Comment: @xeiton We didn't do the pdf part in the end. But we did add an `export as png` button. I suppose you could convert from png to pdf.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes thats a viable solution. Did you use any specific library to convert the pages that were not rendered in DOM to png? Thanks again

Comment: @xeiton sorry for giving you false hope. We did render in the dom actually. It would open a new tab for a split second, render everything, make a png, then close the tab. If you would still like to know the solution, I can link to the code.

Comment: Thanks that's still very helpful. That's what I was thinking to do as a work around too, but I was hoping there is a real solution to this problem. I would still appreciate pointing me to the code you ended up using. Thanks buddy.

Comment: @xeiton [Here's the link](https://github.com/Dryft-bits/ChronoFactorem/blob/17d13856db1760aae8341fc24587b90b1206557c/client/src/components/timetable/ExportPage.jsx). We also the used `htmltocanvas` library.